# APS (Forge) Viewer in Sharepoint - Error loading Autodesk Viewer library

Tags: autodesk-forge, autodesk-viewer, sharepointframework

I am trying to integrate APS Viewer (formerly Forge Viewer) in a Sharepoint webpart using Sharepoint Framework. There is a post in the blog explaining how to do it: https://aps.autodesk.com/blog/sharepoint-online-integration.
I have adapted the code provided, however, I always end up with this error when loading the Viewer. The error occurs when calling Autodesk.Viewing.Initializer function to initialize the viewer. This call fails because

### "ReferenceError: Autodesk is not defined"

yet the library is imported correctly. Anyone knows how can I solve this?

These are the steps we did:

- Create a webpart with Sharepoint Framework. *No Framework* template is selected.
- Add custom js script with functions to load the viewer.
- Import Autodesk js library for Viewer with SPComponentLoader and load custom js script in render() function of our Sharepoint webpart.

  ```js
  SPComponentLoader.loadScript("https://developer.api.autodesk.com/modelderivative/v2/viewers/7.*/viewer3D.min.js");
  SPComponentLoader.loadScript("./js/ForgeTree.js");
  const viewer: any = require("./ForgeViewer.js");
  ```
- Call custom function *launchViewer* from custom js script that calls Autodesk.Viewing.Initializer method. This step fails.

```js
export function launchViewer(urn, viewableId, accessToken) {
  console.log('launchViewer')

  var options = {
    env: 'AutodeskProduction',
    getAccessToken: callback => {
      callback(accessToken, 3600);
    },
    // api: 'derivativeV2' + (atob(urn.replace('_', '/')).indexOf('emea') > -1 ? '_EU' : '') // handle OSS US and EU regions
    api: 'derivativeV2' + (Buffer.from((urn.replace('_', '/')).indexOf('emea') > -1 ? '_EU' : ''), 'base64') // handle OSS US and EU regions
  };

  if (viewer === undefined) {
    Autodesk.Viewing.Initializer(options, () => {
      viewer = new Autodesk.Viewing.GuiViewer3D(document.getElementById('forgeViewer'), { extensions: [ 'Autodesk.DocumentBrowser'] });
      viewer.start();
      var documentId = 'urn:' + urn;
      Autodesk.Viewing.Document.load(documentId, onDocumentLoadSuccess, onDocumentLoadFailure);
    })
  } else {
    var documentId = 'urn:' + urn;
    Autodesk.Viewing.Document.load(documentId, onDocumentLoadSuccess, onDocumentLoadFailure);
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you should simply wait for the `SPComponentLoader.loadScript()` to finish (use `await` or `then()`) as it returns a `Promise<TModule>` 
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/javascript/api/sp-loader/spcomponentloader?view=sp-typescript-latest#@microsoft-sp-loader-spcomponentloader-loadscript-member(1)

I probably got away with not doing that in my code because the authentication is taking place after that call, which gives extra time for `loadScript` to finish

Comment: Thank you very much for your response!
Finally, I managed to load the viewer in the webpart. But now I have another problem.

We want to feed the viewer with files located in **Azure Blob Storage** using **SAS tokens**. Problem is when passing the file url including the SAS token to the loadModel() of the viewer. It encodes the url and the SAS token within, which contains **'%'** characters that are encoded to **'%25'**, making the resource not available due to permission issues (the file in the container is not public).

Do you know any way to avoid this url encoding? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Are you trying to load an SVF file's bubble.json from your server using Document.load()? That's the function that seems to encode query parameters. You can avoid that by placing the query parameters in the "queryParams" property of the "options" object you pass to Document.load()

Comment: I am calling Document.load() like this:
Document.load(<bubble.json url wo SAS token>, onDocumentLoadSuccess, onDocumentLoadFailure, {
        queryParams : { 
          "sv": "...",
          "srt": "...",
          "sp": "...",
          "se": "...",
          "st": "...",
          "spr": "...",
          "sig": "<signature, contains '%'>"
        }
});
SAS token format: "sv=...&ss=...&srt=...&sp=...&se=...&st=...&spr=...".
However, Document.load is not adding these params to the url. Is there something wrong that I am missing? I cannot find any example of this in the docs. Thx.

Comment: It would need to be a single string and not a json object. But then thinking about it more ... I guess you would need those query params for all the other resources the Viewer will try to load, not just for bubble.json.
So I think the best thing is if you implement a proxy: https://aps.autodesk.com/blog/proxying-forge-viewer